# I have a two GPU NVIDIA Driver showing it's one GPU ID using python code on ubuntu

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, linux-device-driver, nvidia

I have a 2 A100 PCIE (80GB VRAM) GPU but NVIDIA is giving me on visible gpu is 1.

Such as a 0 index GPU and I am unable to get the 1 index GPU on ubuntu server.

Here is the code result
[Pytorch Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEet9.png)

what does this command show:

`nvidia-smi`

Here is the result

[Nvidia-SMI Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQWhj.png)

So I want to run both of the GPU with their GPU ID using python in  ubntu server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES env variable?

Try executing the code by setting it to use both GPUs.

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 python your_script.py
```

Comment: Yup but it's doesn't work for me.